# What is a word that describes an entity who is the gold standard in searching for a type of information?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm searching for a particular noun that is used in reference to an entity, perhaps an institution or magazine or similar potential source of information, which is viewed as the go-to source of information on a particular issue.

Sample:

> Stack Overflow is the ____ for programming-related questions.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: That wasn't my tag actually, but I'll do that

Comment: What doesn't "gold standard" convey that you're looking for in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "gold standard" or "standard". It fits well in the sample sentence and are the best terms to convey what you are trying to convey. "Benchmark" could also work.

Comment: Benchmark seems extremely close to what I'm looking for but not the exact word. Thanks for the effort anyway and I'll probably end up using this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply *place*, with the emphasis on the *the*. *The* does most of the work here and it is often stressed in speech as well.

> Stack Overflow is *the* place for programming-related questions.

The relevant sense is one of the usages of the definite article *the*, and it is not really about the noun *place*. Although, *place* is a common noun used colloquially for this kind of context with a stressed *the*.

*[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the)* defines the relevant sense of *the* as below:

> used as a function word to designate one of a class as the best, most typical, best known, or most worth singling out

If a single word is not a must, *go-to place* (or *website, destination* etc.) works also.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but not the term I'm looking for. Thanks a lot though